# How to uncover alternating row colors in beamer class?

Tags: tables, beamer, colortbl

In the howtos section of the beamer documentation (v3.30) I saw the code how to do alternating row colors when displaying tables as a remedy to errors caused by horizontal and vertical lines in tables.
Unfortunately, the code was with errors in my case. I noticed that the `\rowcolors` macro in the documentation is not mentioned in the `colortbl` package documentation by David Carlisle
on 2012/02/13.

Code as in the `beamer` class documentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\rowcolors[]{1}{blue!20}{blue!10} % \rowcolors is not in the colortbl manual
\begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule}cccc} % what's the idea behind !\vrule here, can we avoid it?
Class & A & B & C & D \\\midrule % \midrule instead of the old \hline
X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \pause\\
Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \pause\\
Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ % double backslash was added as it was not there in the manual
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error thrown:

```
Undefined control sequence \end{frame}
```

**Questions:**
What am I missing here? How to fix this error?
What is the best practice to have alternating colors in `beamer` class via cleaner lines of code?

Your answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Pass the the `table` option to the `beamer` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are already using `xcolor`, instead of loading `colortbl`, pass `table` option to `xcolor`. It in turn will load `colortbl`. To avoid the `option clash` I have added the option `table` to beamer class as the option

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
%\usepackage{xcolor}  %% not needed
\usepackage{booktabs}
%% \usepackage{graphicx}  %% not needed.
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\rowcolors[]{1}{blue!20}{blue!10} % \rowcolors is  in the xcolor manual
\begin{tabular}{l|cccc} % \vrule is to Add rule. can use |
Class & A & B & C & D \\\midrule % \midrule instead of the old \hline
X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \pause\\
Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \pause\\
Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  % double backslash not needed
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`!{\vrule}` simply adds a vertical rule. But to use `!` you should load `array` package. You can use `|` also instead.  The advantage of `\vrule` over `|` is that you can vary the thickness of the rule.

Comment: @doctorate Thanks and happy that was useful :)

Comment: `\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}` to make it obvious.